# AngularJs - ag-grid rowData using "controller as" syntax

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

---

[Update] [This Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/pCe3BW) does what I want, ***but*** :

1. it uses `ui-grid`, rather than `ag-grid`.
2. it injects the grid into the module, rather than just the single controller which uses it.

I presume that these changes would be straightforward & will try to work them into my code when I get home in about 14 hours time.

If anyone wants to fork that Plunk and make those changes, I will award a bounty, as this is a good basic start point demo for others wanting to do the same, so that a Plunker would be of general help.

---

---

I am tantalizingly close, but

> Cannot read property 'setRowData' of undefined (caused by "`<ui-view class="ng-scope ng-binding">`")"TypeError: Cannot read property 'setRowData' of undefined

I am using "`controller as`" syntax, hence the `Self`; `(Self = this;`). That is working fine, my problem is when I try to set the `rowData` for an `ag-grid` in the templateURL of a `ui-router` state.

It's much to big to post, but here's the relevant stuff:

```html
<div id="currentCandidatesGridDiv"
     ag-grid="Search_result_controller.currentCandidatesGrid" 
     class="ag-theme-balham red_border"
     style="height: 30%; width:90%">
</div>
```

```js
// lookup the container we want the Grid to use
const currentCandidatesGridDiv = document.querySelector('#currentCandidatesGridDiv');
// create the grid passing in the div to use together with the columns & data we want to use
new agGrid.Grid(currentCandidatesGridDiv, Self.currentCandidatesGrid);

Self.currentCandidatesGrid =
{
    columnDefs: [
       { headerName: "Candidate", field: "candidate_name", sortable: true },
       { headerName: "Skills", field: "skills", sortable: true },
       { headerName: "Start date", field: "start_date", sortable: true }
    ],
    rowData: [],  
    pagination: true,
    paginationAutoPageSize: true,
};
```

Was I correct to `rowData: []`, or ought I to have `rowData: <someVariable>`?

Then I calculate the row data into an array, `Self.currentCandidatesGridRowData`.

When I try to `Self.currentCandidatesGrid.api.setRowData(Self.currentCandidatesGridRowData);` I get error showing above.

[image]

I searched, but cannot find a working Plunker using the `controller as` syntax.

---

[Dupers] 1) the "dupe" question does not have an answer, so is of no use to me
2) my question is specifically about using `Self.xxxGrid.api.setRowData(Self.xxxGridRowData);` with the `controller as syntax. Pleas ere-open. Thnaks

Comment: As I see you are using `gridOptions` object, not directly api right? If so - you need to bind `api` inside `gridReady` function and then you would be able to use any method.

Comment: Sounds like ann aswer :-) Could you please tell me how?

Comment: Share full code controller to be sure pls

Comment: My code is too large, but I did find a very similar Plunker which could be adapted. Please see the update in the question. I will award a bounty if someone else has time to tweak the Plunker.

Comment: I dont need full code but only related to grid initialization and html which is in use (you can also make screenshot)

Comment: Thanks! Grid initalization is in the question at `new agGrid.Grid` and HTML at `<div id="currentCandidatesGridDiv"`...

Comment: I recommend you use gridReady event (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/).   This is really the only reliable replace to know that the api object has been setup.  Within your callback you can safely access the ag-grid api.  For example:      onGridReady: function () {gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();}

Comment: Feel free to post an answer & get some bounty :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## DEMO of ag-Grid with AngularJS using "controller As" syntax

When the ag-Grid script loads, it does not register with AngularJS 1.x. This is because AngularJS 1.x is an optional part of ag-Grid and you need to tell ag-Grid you want to use it:

```
agGrid.initialiseAgGridWithAngular1(angular);

angular.module("example", ["agGrid"])
```

For more information, see

- [Ag-Grid Documentation - Basic AngularJS 1.x Example](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angularjs-grid/#basic-angularjs-1-x-example)

### [The DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/ckGMGAqZgquRcWoR)

```js
agGrid.initialiseAgGridWithAngular1(angular);

angular.module("example", ["agGrid"])
.controller("exampleCtrl", function() {

    var columnDefs = [
        {headerName: "Make", field: "make"},
        {headerName: "Model", field: "model"},
        {headerName: "Price", field: "price"}
    ];

    var rowData = [
        {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000},
        {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000},
        {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000}
    ];

    this.gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        rowData: rowData
    };

})
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
html {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
body {
    padding: 1rem;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src='//unpkg.com/@ag-grid-community/all-modules/dist/ag-grid-community.min.js'>
</script>

<body ng-app="example" ng-controller="exampleCtrl as $ctrl"
      style="height: 100%">

    <div ag-grid="$ctrl.gridOptions" class="ag-theme-balham"
         style="height: 100%;">
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: That works (obviously). Now to translate it into my app ;-) Thanks

Comment: It is the same demo as part 3 of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60479383/5535245) in the question  [AngualrJs: ag-grid in a ui-router view templateUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60475420/angualrjs-ag-grid-in-a-ui-router-view-templateurl). I just changed the template and controller to use "controller as" syntax.

Comment: You obviously know your stuff! I am self-taught, but trying to do things "properly", refactoring my existing SPA to use routing. I would consider switching to Angular, but know enough AngularJs to get by, and will switch to Dart/Flutter soon. Thanks again !  :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Was I correct to `rowData`: [], or ought I to have `rowData: <someVariable>`?

You can even ignore this property in `gridOptions`, but the difference is that:
if you will define `rowData` as an empty array - grid will render handle it as **'No rows to show'**, but if you will not define it, grid will show 'Loading...' - which is more correct, with a delayed request case.

*Besides, you can handle overlay logic by yourself for more details [check here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-overlays/).*

### Now, as I said in comments

> Cannot read property 'setRowData' of undefined

this issue could be caused by using the wrong reference.

First, take a look and check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52764888/4483102) with ag-grid developer comment also.

Secondly, about an issue itself:

```
.controller('yourController', [function() {
  var Self = this;  // here's your controller reference

  // then you will have columns and rowData (probably) 
  // but the most important part is here
  Self.currentCandidatesGrid = {
      ... // anything that you need
     onGridReady: gridReady // major point for future api reference
  }

  function gridReady(params){
     Self.gridApi = params.api;
     Self.columnsApi = params.columnsApi;
  }

}]);
```

And after `gridReady` you would be able to use grid `API` methods via `Self.gridApi`

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://plnkr.co/edit/bn2eeQVDkPICfwXn)