# AngularJs : using ag-grid's $scope.grid.api.setRowData() does not work

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

So, I forked [this simple ag-grid demo Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/u9oyAV) and the forked version is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/gAFp3P9IiFVUbI1M).

The only change is that the old code statically assigned the row data for the `ag-grid` while my fork tries to assign i dynamically, using the API.
i
old:

```
var rowData = [
    {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000},
    {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000},
    {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000}
];

// let the grid know which columns and what data to use
var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: rowData,
    onGridReady: function () {
        gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }
};
```

new:

```
  var rowData = [
    {
      make: "Toyota",
      model: "Celica",
      price: 35000
    },
    {
      make: "Ford",
      model: "Mondeo",
      price: 32000
    },
    {
      make: "Porsche",
      model: "Boxter",
      price: 72000
    }
  ];

  $scope.grid = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: [],
    rowSelection: 'single'
  };

$scope.grid.api.setRowData(rowData);
```

Both in my Plunker, and trying this on `localhost`, the `ag-grid` does not appear.

What am I doing wrongly?

---

[Update] I want to get the data from a server every time the user clicks a button, not just when the grid is ready, and assign the grid's rowData using it's api.

---

[Upperdate] I just noticed on localhost that although `$scope.gridOptions` is defined, `$scope.gridOptions.api` is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I solved it. It is the difference between static & dynamic grid. See [this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/27fv8yBo4qM7k6fB).

Change the HTML to `<div id="myGrid" class="ag-fresh" style="height: 100px;"></div>` (removing the `ag-grid="grid"`), and then, in the controller:

```
var currentCandidatesGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
new agGrid.Grid(currentCandidatesGridDiv, $scope.grid);

$scope.grid.api.setRowData(rowData);
```

I was asking this to help with [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60475420/angualrjs-ag-grid-in-a-ui-router-view-templateurl), and have helped myself a little - just hope that I helped someone else too :-)

Answer (score 1):

The $scope won't have grid.api data instantly after setting. You have to set the data in onGridReady function of the $scope.grid as shown below.
https://plnkr.co/edit/qgPae2iGIl1A9i8O?preview

```js
$scope.grid = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  rowData: [],
  rowSelection: 'single',
  onGridReady: function() {
    $scope.grid.api.setRowData(rowData);
  }
};
```

Comment: Surely that's what that grid's API `setRowData()` function is for (and much more flexible)? The Plunker is uper simplified, *BUT*, I want to get the data from a server every time the user clicks a button, not just when the grid is ready. Can you help with that? Thanks