# Finding a div in an AngualrJS ui-router view, using document.querySelector

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, jquery-selectors

Please see https://jsfiddle.net/mawg/fu9er5cy/3/

I modified an exciting Plunker (hence this is a little more complex than necessary to demonstrate my problem), and in   `<div ng-controller="myController">`

I added  `<div id="myDiv">Can this be found?</div>`

and in `myController`, I added:

```
if (document.querySelector('#myDiv') === null)
{
    alert('Div not found !!');
}
else
{
    alert('yay, Div found :-)');
}
```

The div can be seen by selecting "book info" and I naively thought that the controller's code, and, hence, `document.querySelector()` would be executed when I navigate to that state's view.

As you can see, it is evaluated immediately, and says that the div can not be found.

As you can also see, from my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61085607/angularjs-using-ag-grids-scope-grid-api-setrowdata-does-not-work), I only want to find the div when I change state & navigate to the state which shows that view and, hence, its controller, so that I can `document.querySelector` the div and inject an `ag-grid` into it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

1) Your `<div id="myDiv">Can this be found?</div>` exists in:

```
$stateProvider.state("details", {
   url: "/details",
```

and this is not your default route: `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/")`

so let's change it to `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/details")`

2) I don't know the golal of:

```
getID: function($timeout) {
    return $timeout(function() {
      console.log("value resolved")
        //$scope.Company="Cognizant";
    }, 1000)
  }
```

but it stucks your route for 1 sec. You start to render the view only after 1 sec.

so I removed this code snippet.

3) You try to check the id in the same digest cycle with view rendering, so you get a failure. to trigger the digest cycle or enter to the end of *queue* you can add some zero timeout:

```
 $timeout(function(){
  if (document.querySelector('#myDiv') === null)
    {
        alert('Div not found !!');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('yaya, Div found :-)');
    }  
  },0)
```

---

fixed example <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/452jpq6t/)</kbd>

Hope it will give you some input to figure out :)

Comment: Thanks for such a quick and detailed response :-) 1) I *want* to be able to find a div in any state/view, not just the default 2) yup, that's someone else's code & not relevant here 3) but this still checks for existance when the Plunker is loaded & I want to check the first time the state is entered  (maybe each time, for flexibility?)

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica you can't check the div in each state because you call the check in  `myController` that is global. Do it in `run` call when state is changed `$stateChangeSuccess`, here is second example: http://jsfiddle.net/e0yobcqg/

Comment: Thanks. I picked a lousy example. I had thought that that one had one controller per state/view, which is what my app will have. And I just want to add a grid in one view. Because I need to use ag-grid's `grid.api.SetRowData()`, I need to have a dynamic grid, not static, which means that I need to locate it. I guess that I need to make abetter Plunker. Yours still finds the div on loading the Plunker

Comment: Ok, I owe you a missive apology, for not posting my own Plunker. Modifying someone else's made things too complex, so I have made a minimal demo. I have also posted an answer, which hope that you won't mind, but it doesn't look like you need the points. Alas, the demo works the way I wanted it to, but by my full app does not. I plan to take the demo & drop my app into it, piece by piece & hope that it works. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can run a check whenever something in the DOM changes, and then **remove** the listener, once the `div` is found

```
function func() {
  if (document.querySelector('#myDiv') !== null) {
    document.documentElement.removeEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', func);
    alert('yaya, Div found :-)');
  } 
}

document.documentElement.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', func);
func();
```

Answer (score 0):

in trying to reply to @Maxim, I coded [a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vXzfDKZn7FMW4aBh?preview) from scratch.

It does exactly what I want it to.

It seems that every time a router state is entered, its controller is initialized, and in the initialization code I can find the div.

There is something wrong with my much larger app, which does not find the div. So, I will start with the Plunker and drop my app into it, piece by piece, until I get it to work.

I post this answer in the hope that it will help someone in future. Here's the code:

alpha.html

```
<div>
    <h1>Alpha</h1>
</div>

<a ui-sref="beta" ui-sref-active="beta">Beta</a>
```

beta.html

```
<div id="beta_div">
    <h1>Beta</h1>
</div>

<a ui-sref="alpha" ui-sref-active="alpha">Alpha</a>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript"
        src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript"
        src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.13/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

    <script type="application/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="controllers.js"></script>
</head>

<body ui-view></body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ui.router'
]);

angular.module('app').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/alpha');

        $stateProvider.state('alpha', {
            url: '/alpha',
            templateUrl: './alpha.html',
            controller: 'alphaController'
        });

        $stateProvider.state('beta', {
            url: '/beta',
            templateUrl: './beta.html',
            controller: 'betaController'
        });
    }  
]);
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('app').controller('alphaController', ['$state',
    function ($state) {

    }
]);

angular.module('app').controller('betaController', ['$state',
    function ($state) {
        if (document.querySelector('#beta_div') === null) {
            alert('Div not found !!');
        }
        else {
            alert('Yay, Div found :-)');
        }        
    }
]);
```